# Perl-Copying file from one location to other but content not copying

Tags: perl

I am writing a script in perl where I am creating a file and getting input from user for file but when I am copying that file to other location the file is copying but it is empty only. My code is

```
# !/usr/bin/perl -w
for($i = 1;$i<5;$i++)
{
  open(file1,"</u/man/fr$i.txt");
  print "Enter text for file $i";
  $txt = <STDIN>;
  print file1 $txt;
  open(file2,">/u/man/result/fr$i.txt");
  while(<file1>)
  {
     print file2 $_;
  }
  close(file1);
  close(file2);
}
```

fr1 to fr4 are creating but these are empty. like when I run my code it is asking for input i provide the input and code run without error but still the files are empty. Please help.
in line number 4 I changed < to > also as I thought for creating new file it might need that but still it is not working

Comment: You open `file1` for _reading_ (with `<...`) but then you write to it ...?

Comment: i changed that one for writing also but still it is not working

Comment: What do you want to do: (1) Open an existing file for reading and copy it to another  --OR-- (2) Open a new file for writing, write to it, then copy it to another ... ?

Comment: i want to create 4 files then copy them to other location.

Comment: i tried first opening file to write then opening same for read and then i move but still result is same

Comment: Always check the return value of [open](http://p3rl.org/open): `open my $FH1, '<', "/u/man/fr$i.txt" or die "fr$i.txt: $!"`

Comment: OK.  1) You must open the file for writing in order to write to it  (2) you have to first close that filehandle in order to be able to then read from it.

Comment: @choroba I tried your suggestion and my code is running and not throwing any error or not stopping it is executing full but still same result

Comment: @zdim I open file1 first then I close file1 then only I opened file2  and created a new handler file3 which is having the file in read mode then only i moved the file  but still it is not working

Comment: Posted an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the filehandle that was written to in order to be able to read from that file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

for my $i (1..4)
{
    my $file = "file_$i.txt";
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    say $fh "Written to $file";

    # Opening the same filehandle first *closes* it if already open
    open $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    my $copy = "copy_$i.txt";
    open my $fh_cp, '>', $copy  or die "Can't open $copy: $!";

    while (<$fh>) {
        print $fh_cp $_;
    }
    close $fh_cp;  # in case of early errors in later iterations
    close $fh;
}
```

This creates the four files, `file_1.txt` etc, and their copies, `copy_1.txt` etc.

Please note the **compulsory** checking whether `open` worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried this one now my code work fine

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to a filehandle that's not open for writing. You can't read from a filehandle that's not open for reading. Never ignore the return value of [open](http://p3rl.org/open).

```
# !/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;                              # Be warned about mistakes.
use strict;                                # Prohibit stupid things.

for my $i (1 .. 4) {                       # lexical variable, range
    open my $FH1, '>', "/u/man/fr$i.txt"   # 3 argument open, lexical filehandle, open for writing
        or die "$i: $!";                   # Checking the return value of open

    print "Enter text for file $i: ";
    my $txt = <STDIN>;
    print {$FH1} $txt;

    open my $FH2, '<', "/u/man/fr$i.txt"   # Reopen for reading.
        or die "$i: $!";
    open my $FH3, '>', "/u/man/result/fr$i.txt" or die "$i: $!";
    while (<$FH2>) {
        print {$FH3} $_;
    }
    close $FH3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i used and it help a lot as my file was not opening properly

Answer (score 0):

I opened the file in write mode using filehandler1 Then i again opened the file in read mode using same filehandler1 then I opened filehandler2 for destiantion So it is working fine for me then.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("cp myfile1.txt /somedir/myfile2.txt")
`cp myfile1.txt /somedir/myfile2.txt`
```